# Is it possible to make multiple Bootstrap popovers more DRY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've run into a problem, where I have more than 10 popovers in one table. They all should display a popover on hover, and have a similar html, but with some differences in content. I made it the easiest way, but I feel there must be a smarter way to do this.

Is it possible to make this js code more DRY?

```
 $('#static-pop-1').popover({
        'trigger': 'hover',
        'placement': 'bottom',
        'html': true,
        'content': '<div class="static-popover"><span>Hey!</span></div>'
    });

 $('#static-pop-2').popover({
        'trigger': 'hover',
        'placement': 'bottom',
        'html': true,
        'content': '<div class="static-popover"><span>Hey 2!</span></div>'
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/axt63orn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want the popover to just say `Hey 1`, `Hey 2` etc. but actually set a different content in each, but keep the rest of the settings the same, you can do

```
var settings = {
    trigger   : 'hover',
    placement : 'bottom',
    html      : true
}

$('#static-pop-1').popover($.extend({}, settings, {
    content: '<div class="static-popover"><span>Hey!</span></div>'
}));

$('#static-pop-2').popover($.extend({}, settings, {
    content: '<div class="static-popover"><span>Hey 2!</span></div>'
}));

$('#static-pop-3').popover($.extend({}, settings, {
    content: '<div class="static-popover"><span>Hey 3!</span></div>'
}));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/axt63orn/3/)

or you could use a function

```
function setting(text) {
    return {
        trigger   : 'hover',
        placement : 'bottom',
        html      : true,
        content   : '<div class="static-popover"><span>'+text+'</span></div>'
    }
}

$('#static-pop-1').popover(setting('Hey!'));
$('#static-pop-2').popover(setting('Hey 2!'));
$('#static-pop-3').popover(setting('Hey 3!'));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/axt63orn/4/)

Comment: It could be worth noting that settings will be changed by those calls, and would therefore be 'tainted' for any later usage. It may not make a difference, but if settings should be kept as-is, `$.extend({},settings,{content:''})` could be beneficial  as it will copy the settings object and not edit it directly

Comment: What about the HTML? Is it possible to make a variable out of it, and change only the content of <span>?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - that's true, changed it to use an empty object, as that's how it should've be done.

Comment: @Punkdog - like that ?

Comment: Wow, this helped me a lot. Can I insert some more html markup in .popover(setting())? Just looked it up - I can. You, sir, are a genius.

Comment: Sure, you can change the HTML string in the function ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data` attribute:

```
<a class="pop" id="static-pop-1" data-mycontent="Hey 1!" title="">Content 1</a>

$('.pop').popover({
    'trigger': 'hover',
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'html': true,
    'content': function(){
        return '<div class="static-popover"><span>'+$(this).data('mycontent')+'</span></div>';
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/wvL0hjzv/)

Comment: I like this, but the function does nothing, setting the data attribute gets picked up by the plugin, so it doesn't return the div or the span, but it's still a lot easier. [Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/270b4jq0/1/) without the function

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But the point is that you can then manipulate the content as you wish inside the `function(el){`.

Comment: Well, it does'nt! Inspecting the popover, the markup is never inserted, and adding a console log in the function shows that it's never executed -> http://jsfiddle.net/270b4jq0/2/

Comment: Nothing is impossible :)